# How to do numerical aproximation of integral in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, wolfram-mathematica, integral

I'm new using Sympy, and people told me that I would be able to perform numerical approximations of integral with Sympy. What I have tried is this:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy.abc import x
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_latex="mathjax")

x = symbols('x')
def Kpol(w,q,thresh,xf,rmf):
    fw = 3.*(1.+w)/(5.+3.*w)
    Krm = (thresh/fw/rmf/rmf)*((1+(1/q))/(1+(1/q)*(xf/rmf)**(2*(q+1))))
    return Krm
def raizpol(w,q,thresh,xf,rmf):
    raiz = sqrt(1.-Kpol(w,q,thresh,xf,rmf)*xf*xf)
    return raiz
def integrando(w,q,thresh,xf,rmf):
    integrando = 1/(1-raizpol(w,q,thresh,xf,rmf))
    return integrando


rtil = integrando(1/3.,1.,0.5.,x,1.)/x
integral = integrate(rtil,(x,oo,x))
integral.doit()
```

but all I get is no-evaluated integral:

[image]

I would like to know how to evaluate this expression in an approx way for each x. I think I know how to do this in Mathematica but I would like to know how to do it in sympy.

Regards, Isaac.

EDIT[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4H96.png): This is the difference between Mathematica and Python. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDzhZ.jpg Mathematica gets the integral well done, but python has problem with convergence?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a numerical approximation. Your integral has an upper limit of `x` meaning that it cannot be computed numerically.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain. What I have tried first is to get an analytic expression for the integral, whose result was an attempt. I want to know if there is a way to compute that integral in Sympy for a specified x. Is more clear now?

Comment: Is it ok that the radicant may become negative?

Comment: Yeah, totally my bad in that part, one parameter of rtil was wrong, I updated it. I could do the integral with any problem with mathematica, but in python I have problems. Check this image: https://imgur.com/1Wtk7Ry. Mathematica is the line. Python are the points.

Answer (score 0):

Numerical integrals can be evaluated as follows

```py
x_val=100; # a numeric value to substitute
integral.subs(x, x_val).evalf()
```

Slow, but should be robust, I tried scipy quad and the results are wildly inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks for the fast anwser. My idea is to use this 200 times in each time step, so I'll need something faster. I have tested this and for each integral it takes 30s, while doing it in wolfram alpha does it in ms. I'm reading there is something lambdify, is it faster? What do you mean by scipy quad?